# Cannot import package despite successful pip install

Tags: installation, pip, package, modulenotfounderror

After running pip install . in docker container over the setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('../requirements.txt') as f:
    required_packages = f.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name='ethically',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests"]),
    install_requires=[required_packages])
```

I checked with pip freeze that the package is installed:
Seeing `ethically @ file:///` indicates that it is installed.

After opening the Python terminal, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ethically'
```

Package file structure:

```
project
  - ethically
    - __init__.py
  - setup.py
  - requirements.txt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried running `pip install -e .` and reshuffling file structure.

**RESOLVED**

Needed to run `python setup.py bdist_wheel sdist` before `pip install .`